# Заменить определенные значения во всех файлах excel в папке и подпапках

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как кодом vba excel 2007 автоматизировать следующее:
В определенной папке и в ее подпапках лежат файлы excel ".xltx" (.xl*). Нужно во всех этих файлах найти в диапазоне ячеек "A1:T7" значения "2018" либо "2019" либо "2020" И заменить на "2021"? с сохранением файлов.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вообще-то это плохая идея. Старайтесь всегда выполнить задачу так, чтобы можно было вернуться к предыдущему варианту данных. Другими словами, Ваша задача лучше формулируется как "Создать в указанной папке копию исходной папки со всеми вложенными подпапками и скопировать в неё все файлы *,xl*, попутно заменяя значения в диапазоне A1:T7 на 2021"

Comment: Перебираете файлы (FSO.Folder.Files). Каждый файл - Load-Replace-SaveAs-Close.

Comment: Ищите решение задач: рекурсивный перебор папок и подпапок; открытие книг в цикле; замена значений; сохрание книг (по совету  JohnSUN - "сохранить как").  А еще: проверка наличия исходной папки; проверка наличия нужного листа в книге; создание каталога для сохранения книг.

Comment: С "заменой значений", боюсь, не всё так просто. этот самый *либо "2019" либо "2020"* может оказаться частью даты. С частью строки или отдельным числом проблем не должно возникнуть (обычный поиск/замена), а вот с датами, возможно, придется повозиться.